# Templated function return type from return type of a lambda

Tags: c++, templates, types, lambda

I'm trying to work out the required return type for a function that returns an unordered map keyed on the value type of the templated iterator Iter and the result of a lambda(F) when called with the value of the iterator. I'm compiling with GCC 4.9.1 in C++1y mode.

This is as far as I've got, but this could be heading in entirely the wrong direction, as I have very little templating experience.

```
template<typename Iter, typename Func>
unordered_map<Iter::value_type, decltype(F(*Start)) Map(Iter Start, Iter End, Func F)
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You need `typename` before `Iter::value_type`.

Comment: Do you actually want an `unordered_map` with the full contents for a result, or something that maps results dynamically on an as-needed basis, vaguely like Haskell does?

Comment: Probably not.  But food for thought: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51164246f5ddefd1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template< class Iter, class Func>
auto Map( Iter Start, Iter End, Func F )
    -> unordered_map<typename Iter::value_type, decltype(F(*Start))>
```

---

More generally you can [leverage `std::function`](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/resultof-a-function-with-c11/#comments) to deduce the result type of a known function type,

```
template< class Func >
struct ResultOf
{
    typedef typename std::function<
        typename std::remove_pointer<Func>::type
        >::result_type T;
};
```

Comment: The trailing return type worked brilliantly. I hadn't even heard of it until now. Thanks!

Comment: For people who see this in the future, the first part of the answer is missing a closing angle bracket in the type specifier.